# The [code-review] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag is in phase 4 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). The question and comments have been cleaned to allow for on-topic discussion on this tag; please keep it that way.

If you want to discuss the process itself, post a new question on Meta or visit the [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).*

Should the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag be removed?

The description states:

> On Stack Overflow, questions to review code are generally off-topic. It is recommended to post such questions on the Code Review sister site.

In my opinion it follows the rule#2 of the [Does this tag even need to be burninated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and it doesn't add additional information to the question.

I think we could blacklist this tag like it's already done for code-golf.

Comment: This tag exists?!  Kill it with fire.  But be judicious about what is burned and why; some relate to VCS-like review tools (which may do with a retagging) and others relate to processes (which may do with closure).

Comment: @Makoto Yes maybe we could create the tag code-review-tools then (or something more specific).

Comment: There is also [tag:review] and [tag:coding-style] which can probably go too.

Comment: 3 years later, Code Review still advises _"The Stack Overflow Help Center doesn't say that code reviews are explicitly off-topic there."_ https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778

Comment: Stats 39 mins after featuring Q: +103, -1. 3 answers: answer 1 (burn review and code-review) +19, -1 ; answer 2 (agree to burn, code-review) +15, -2; answer 3 (be carefull) =11, -2

Comment: Final stats: Q: +163/-4, 7 answers: answer 1 (burn review and code review) +53 / - 2; answer (be careful) +30/-3 : answer (agree code-review): +27/-3; answer (yes): +2 /- 1; answer(codereview historical) +4/-3; answer (not anymore): +4/-6; answer (cautious): +1 / -4

Comment: Reviewing code is technically not a question, more like requesting help from the community

Comment: What about a tag that describes not a need to review some code, but the code review process itself? About methods of code review and tools used for that.

Answer (score 60):

[review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) and [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) should both be burned.

According to [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/code-review-graduation) and [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/code-review-se-is-graduating) posts, CR is technically graduated. Any allegations of CR not being a full member of the SE community hold no ground.

On top of that, as the original question states, [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) is off-topic for Stack Overflow. [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) is even worse. Not only is it vague and off-topic, but it's also used for many different type of questions. There's nothing coherent in the questions tagged with it.

- [How is your experience with Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190839/1014587)
- [How long does it take for Dropbox to review application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6106977/1014587)
- [How do I give out free review copies of my paid android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050255/1014587)
- [How to display rating summary in product listing in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12370028/1014587)
- [How to handle LaTeX/PDF doc reviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10501780/1014587)

Comment: Would [tag:coding-style] fit into the burn list as well?

Comment: Just FYI, we would not be burninating [review] as it's a separate tag and [code-review] is a fairly large tag

Answer (score 27):

I would be careful. TFS has a feature called ["Code review"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mvpawardprogram/new-code-review-feature-in-visual-studio-2012). Some of the questions with this tag are about that.

Comment: Could rename those ones `tfs-code-review` or something

Comment: However teh code-review tag is not that, as itself explains: "Code Reviews are done in various forms such as pair programming, informal walkthroughs, and formal inspections."

Comment: This is a good point. We should create a new tag for those questions, since questions about programming tools are on-topic.

Comment: @EJoshuaS having a tag for a specific feature of a specific tool seems to be too... specific. What would be the problem with simply tagging as the tool itself?

Comment: @Braiam You're probably right - the questions would probably be ok with just [tfs] or [visual-studio]

Comment: Just FYI, I created the tag and all the related TFS stuff is being retagged

Answer (score 24):

[code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)  exists and more than 1K questions are tagged with it.

If this is kept then there could be many other tags coming like [interview-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-question), [do-it-for-me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-it-for-me), etc.

As per Stack Overflow policy this tag should be removed, as there is a dedicated Stack Exchange site  for this purpose: [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [do-it-for-me] may actually be  a useful tag because then any question that used it could get downvoted and closed faster.

Comment: Love it, that's a great idea - but lets extend the tag to [i-have-no-clue-about-IT-but-got-hired-anyway-so-can-you-please-do-it-for-me]

Answer (score 15):

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [tfs-code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-code-review) for questions about the [TFS Code-Review feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2012/09/04/new-code-review-feature-in-visual-studio-2012/).

## Progress:

The [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=code-review),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-review%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-review%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-review%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-review%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181359/burnination-progress-for-the-code-review-tag)

[image: Gemmy's burnination progress chart (this is updated from time-to-time; see burnination chat room for the most recent)]

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) has more than 1000 questions. Therefore, do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and vote to close the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree, this tag should be gone.

As per the current policies, questions on Stack Overflow are required to have a clear problem statement, and for debugging questions an MCVE is also required.

Code Review questions inherently aren't suitable on SO (there's a site for that now, and not to mention its historical facts) because they cannot have a clear problem statement, otherwise that'd make them debugging questions and consequently the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag unsuitable for them.

Concluding that, [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) does not belong on SO and is better kicked out.

Answer (score 2):

[code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

Answer (score -3):

[code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) is historical. `codereview.stackexchange.com` didn't always exist. I kinda feel the correct solution is to identify the code-review questions (should be most of them tagged [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)) and actually migrate them over.

But the burninate process is completely unsuitable for that.

Comment: The existing policy has (always, to my knowledge) been that old content is not migrated, even if both sites agree such a question would be better suited to another site. So I doubt this would ever happen.

Comment: It's not just the tradition isn't to migrate old content; old posts can't be migrated, only new ones can.

Comment: In such cases there could be value in making a tag "historical" and not allowing it's use on any new questions while still being displayable on old ones; but that would be a feature request separate from the existing cleanup processes.

Answer (score -4):

> Should the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag be removed?

Not anymore. Some cleanup may be appropriate, but the tag is fine.

The vast majority of new questions in this tag aren't *requests* for code review. Instead, most of what I see is questions about how to use online code review features in source code management tools like Github or Gerrit. These questions are entirely on-topic for SO -- the tag name might not be ideal, but the content is fine.

Comment: The reason I didn't find this compelling is that people were just tagging those tools as [code-review], even when there was no review. The Qs are on-topic and can remain, but the correct usage to make this a useful tag just wasn't there.

Answer (score -5):

I'd be a bit cautious when it comes to justifying the removal of the tag *solely* based on the existence of codereview.SE (which most replies here are trying to suggest). I'm not a user of that site, but I'm an avid follower of [their Using CR for <strike>dummies</strike> SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) FAQ. They probably know best. Quoting that document:

> **Before referring a Stack Overflow user to Code Review**, consider: *Is it really off-topic for Stack Overflow?* Just because a question is said to have "working code" and seems to be on-topic on Code Review, doesn't mean that it is automatically off-topic for Stack Overflow. There are many questions that are on-topic on both sites. [The Stack Overflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) doesn't say that code reviews are explicitly off-topic there, so don't migrate for the sake of migration.

Of course we're not talking about migration, but at least as far as the kind people at Code Review are concerned code-review questions aren't automatically off topic here. Especially since there are a lot of code-review questions that aren't on topic there: I can imagine someone producing a function or part of a function that they have identified as a bottleneck. It might have an MCVE, everything necessary to put the problem in context and help resolve the bottleneck, but it's not a good fit for CR.

I'm not saying that we *should* keep the tag, I'm merely trying to argue that we should decide the legitimacy of the tag based on our own domain alone, without considering other sites on the network.

Comment: That text has been there since 2015. Things have changed since then. Questions asking "I have this code, how can it be better" are almost always POB (primarely opinion based). CR has matured a lot since then, and is **the goto site** for code reviewing.

Comment: @Luuklag that answer was last edited in February. I imagine if it no longer applied it would have been removed from the FAQ since.