# Need to review the [code-review]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

In 2014, the community largely [agreed that code-review is not a good tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278138/remove-the-code-review-tag), because the tag wiki itself says the tag is off-topic.  Questions under that tag should probably be on CR.SE anyway.

But the tag still has over 1,000 questions, so it looks like nobody ever followed up on that.  Are we still in favor of burninating it?

Oh, and here's the link: [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)

Comment: The notion that burning the [code-review] tag will stop SO-users from asking for code reviews is wishful thinking.  The tag wiki is pretty useful.

Comment: @Hans: Is it still possible to blacklist tags?  Or perhaps we could add a warning similar to the one you get when tagging a meta post with [burninate-request].

Comment: Not "we", it has to be done by SE employees like @Shog9

Comment: [tag:code-review] & [tag:review] both should be treated similarly to [tag:tutorial].