# Why is there a [code-review] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, code-review-se

There is [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Why on earth does Stack Overflow need a [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag? I think it should be burninated. There is [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278138/remove-the-code-review-tag) on this, but as far as I can tell, nothing has been done.

Comment: I'd hazard [code-review] was created before the site, and haven't been cleared since. the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-review/info) part of the tag seems to support this.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate; how does one ask for a burnination of a tag which was previously burninated, if we're going to close them as duplicates (of **two year old questions** at that)? Since we rarely if ever get a tag blacklisted, how is one supposed to get the burn done?