# Review [review]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

We have a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) tag, with 388 questions and 36 followers.  Its wiki is:

> For questions about systems that implement reviews, such as an e-commerce platform that has a reviews component. DO NOT use this tag for questions about code reviews.

If this tag was used properly, it might have *some* value, but it's not being used properly.  Looking through the first page, most questions are about Apple's app review or about code reviews.

Should we burninate it or replace it with something else?

Comment: This tag earned a dishonorable mention in [the answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278138/remove-the-code-review-tag)

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, I didn't see that.  Does that count as a dupe?

Comment: Don't think so, they're talking about different tags.

Comment: So somebody can be an expert in review components? What would be an on topic question be for a review component? Why does the review component throw a ReviewNotFoundException? I think it is not being used properly, because it has no value.