# Why can't I use "code-review" as a tag to ask about the Visual Studio "Code Review" feature?

Tags: support, tags

Why can't I use [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)as a tag to ask about the Visual Studio "Code Review" feature?

I did read the "error" message about "code-review", but it then blocked me from using what seemed the most logical tag.

I did not want to request a "code review" - I wanted to ask about the Visual Studio feature named "code review".

Comment: There is an [old burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278138/remove-the-code-review-tag) for that tag but it doesn't look like it went anywhere. It also looks like the official site definition is for code reviews that happen in person, so using it for a feature in a program wouldn't be correct anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-review/info

Comment: What error message did you get?  What did it say?

Comment: Because you are tagging your question as [code-review], not [visual-studio-code-review]. You want to tag a feature, use the full name of said feature.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I would suggest that you use visual studio related tags. "code-review" would be way too generic even without other issues.