# Why are we keeping "how do you compute password complexity?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, vote-to-delete, locked-posts

[This isn't even a programming question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392928) It's a thinly veiled "what algo should I use to check password strength", which we all known the modern answer to `password.lenght() > 12`. It doesn't offer anything novel and I'm sure guys at Sec.SE would tore this apart and make an actual good questions about it, like [How can we accurately measure a password entropy range?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4630/27973) and [How reliable is a password strength checker?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2687/27973). No information on this question follows reasonable security practices and misinforms users that this is a acceptable practice.

PS. if you measure password strength by other than length, I implore you to stop those practices and remember [xkcd 936](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: @usr2564301 note, that moderators were using at some point a script that made bulk actions on several posts on their behalf, ans such script at some point wasn't selecting the correct posts. I'm not sure that's what happened on this specific case.

Comment: That question is definitely on-topic here. It should not be closed, locked, or deleted.

Comment: @TinyGiant where in the help center says so?

Comment: I really need to introduce a metric when I ask these kind of things "Can Braiam answer it?" If the answer is yes, then it's obviously off topic. I'm not a programmer nor a software developer in any sense of the word.

Comment: @Braiam I don't understand why you are so active on meta here if you're not a programmer. A person cannot claim to be an expert of what is on topic here and say they're not a programmer. My brain when *boing* lol

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't *call* myself I programmer, that's not my profession. I write code and I want the resources for allowing me to write programs to be acceptable. That makes me an enthusiast in programming.

Comment: @Braiam thanks for clarifying that. I can see from your network profile you're active in related industries and you do have a decentish rep here. I think what we're looking at are the overlap between programming and related areas. There's shade of grey, I'm easy to go with which ever flow people want.

Answer (score 8):

Let's take this in three phases.

- Is the question objective?
- Is the question clear?
- Is the question answerable?

First, let's talk about the question's objectivity. **At its core, the question is asking about an algorithm to use.**  Irrespective of if you *disagree* with the algorithm or approach, [questions about algorithms are *perfectly* on topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Second, let's talk about the clarity of the question  The question *could* benefit from some clarity and proofreading, since the layout of the question is a bit awkward.

Third, let's talk about if the question is answerable.  Seems reasonable enough to answer; the algorithm *could* be improved on, or one could use a library.  Not seeing anything here that makes the question unanswerable.

---

Kinda reads like you found a question you don't like and are trying to justify closing it. It's not the most significant question in the world...but I don't see a reason to kick it to the curb.

Comment: @Braiam: If you want to comment on my answer, then you can feel encouraged to comment. No need to edit out parts of my answer you don't like.

Comment: So, you want me to *flag it as rude* instead? You are misrepresenting my reasoning and reasons. At least, Yvette had the responsibility of showing the comments that motivated this question and the why. Read that answer instead of making baseless assumptions about facts.

Comment: @Braiam:  You're entitled to your opinion on this, but I'm going to stick to my original edit on this.  I do admit that there is some frustration oozing out from some of the interactions I've had with you over the last two weeks over questions which seem to be otherwise fine which you raise strong objections to.  My opinion stands; you're free to disagree with it but I don't believe that I am being explicitly rude to you.  We all have questions we don't like, but that doesn't give us the power to *close* them.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's important to give people the full background on a post when reviewing why it is in it's current state, if all the information is not available on the post.

For complete context:

This question was reviewed, closed and deleted during the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) [burnination][1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278138/the-code-review-tag-has-been-burninated). [I deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/392928/revisions).

The origins of this question lock come from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378437/3956566) and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378552/3956566).
Where I edited out the burnt tag, undeleted it and locked it for the time being (until there was more of a consensus).

Under which there was this comment discussion:

[image]

My take on it, is it does no harm to the site. The purpose of the site is to have a good repository of programming questions and answers.

We can reopen it, make it into a community wiki, where no more answers can be added, but the answers can be edited and updated, leave it as it is or redelete it.

Personally, I would like to see it edited and improved and so will unlock it, now it's being discussed here in more detail with more attention.

Comment: Since you want a "good repository of programming questions and answers". I'm not programmer, and I'm capable of answering that question. Do you believe a good programming question that can be answered correctly and with a good answer by a not programmer is a good programming question? Why a good programming question need not a programmer to answer it?

Comment: That actually works the other way too - If you’re not a programmer, you’re probably not in a good position to understand what a good programming-related question is, whether you feel you can come up with an answer to it or not. So really you should really be listening to all the programmers telling you it’s fine.

Comment: I mean, I’m not a chef, but I can still tell you how to make a lasagne. Doesn’t mean I’ll go and tell a bunch of chefs that they’re making their dinner wrong

Comment: @Clive but being able to answer questions that is dedicated to answer questions "unique to software development" is a bad thing. I don't call myself programmer, I know how to code. A programmer is dedicated to software development. That question doesn't need anyone dedicated to software development to answer it, less to understand it. That needs someone well versed in statistics (which btw, is one of the things I dedicate myself professionally).

Comment: Sorry but your thinking is very much broken on this, maybe you’re too close to it or something to see the obviousness. You can argue whether or not you deserve the label “programmer”, but if you can and do code, you’re a programmer. Simple as that. You could perhaps argue that this specific question is also answerable from the point of view of a statistician, but what you’re currently saying is that because you can answer a question, and because you’re not a professional programmer, that the question can’t be about programming, or have a programming focus. Which of course makes no sense

Comment: I gave it a try, but [the edit didn't take.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21855366) If someone can do it better, I'm all for it.

Comment: @Clive (please, when you respond to comments, include the mention) the problem is that, as I mentioned on this question, you don't need a programmer to make a good password strength algorithm. You need a statistician/mathematician with expertise in cryptography to make sure the algo is not being incredibly misleading. I wouldn't trust a programmer to be able to really calculate what makes a password good, and implementations of this kind are the worse, since it gives a false sense of security. If you want to get a good way to calculate password entropy, ask those people.

Comment: (cont.) A programmer should only worry about the implementation.

Comment: Well I, and evidently many others, who _are_ programmers, and as such are more qualified to make this judgement, disagree with your assessment. You’re just going have to deal with that, and accept that the question has been declared very much on topic. There’s nothing more to discuss here so I’ll bow out now.

Comment: @Braiam yes I agree with the ping. I have to read them carefully to be sure who is being addressed without the ping.

Comment: @Clive well, they can disagree, that just mean that they are not only wrong, but **dangerously wrong**, since we are talking about **security** here. I prefer that people keeps **their opinions** when talking about security, and leave those issues to people that actually dedicated time to research the topic on profundity. Those keep facts very at heart and don't just throw opinions.

Comment: @Braiam Once again, you’ve already professed that you’re not in a position to make that assessment - you’re _not a programmer nor a software developer in any sense of the word_, remember? Your words, not mine. So I’ll polietly ask you to leave this decision to the experts, know when you’re beaten, and be gracious rather than belligerent about it. Thanks and bye!

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm not following this thread closely, but just to note — please try not to use Community Wiki to somehow justify/allow a question which otherwise would not be allowed. That's not a proper use case for Community Wiki. That feature probably should have been deprecated eons ago (a conversation for another time).

Comment: @RobertCartaino the wiki answer lock? Or community wiki generally?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't know what a wiki answer lock is, so I guess I don't know the full context of how it's being used.

Comment: @RobertCartaino that's what I'm referring to, not a community wiki. It's where the question is locked and the answers can be updated and curated as a community wiki.  Useful to prevent more answers, but allow editing.

Answer (score 3):

As others has already pointed out this question is very much on topic.

While there are elements of gamification on Stack Overflow, at its core it is a Q/A site driven by people who program for people who program or something to that effect, not a game to see how many questions we can delete.

The rules are there to make sure we **can** remove Questions and Answers that detract from the quality, **not** to enforce that we **have to** delete everything that can be somehow construed as breaking one nor another rule.

Answer (score -1):

So there are numerous problems with this post, but first and foremost *it's simply not on topic*.  The question isn't asking *how to use code or programming related tools to solve a problem*, which would be on topic, they're fundamentally asking *what should the business requirements of their program be*.  An on topic question would be one that seeks to figure out how to *implement* the requirements that they have, not in picking what the requirements are.  That's not a programming problem.  It doesn't require programming expertise.  It's *entirely* unrelated to the field, other than for the fact that a programmer will need to implement it *once they eventually figure out what their requirements should be*.

Additionally the question is *also* extremely broad, and extremely subjective.  There's *all sorts* of information to take into consideration when determining how you want to determine the strength of a password, and those criteria will also need to evolve quite a bit over time as the methods and means of attacking passwords changes (things that change a lot over time are inherently a poor fit for SE sites, given their model).  Additionally there's no objective criteria specified for what a "strong" password is, either in the question, or in general.  How good a password *needs* to be will depend on context and how important the security of whatever is being protected is.  There is no *objective* way to determine if any given answer is correct.

Answer (score -9):

- Is the question objective?

No. It asks whenever the algorithms is good enough at evaluating password strengths, this is subjective and depends on how you want to evaluate said strength.

> I'm concerned by the fact that my algorithm would rate X password with *undesirable results*

- Is the question clear?

Yes, at making sure the subjective evaluation is answered.

- Is the question answerable?

Yes, but that's not the kind of questions we are asking on SO, is it? Evaluating whenever or not an algorithm is good at evaluating password complexity isn't something a programmer is expected to be good at. That's left for the cryptanalyst and mathematicians to evaluate.