# What is the proper usage of the [language-lawyer] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There have been various mentions of the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag; however, they all discussed a specific case. Recently, there was a clash of perspectives about that tag over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75534848/2370483) (locked for now to prevent Meta effect), which saw an edit war erupt (with lots of flags to boot).

The catch here is that the tag itself is vague as to what its usage is:

> For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages.

I'm not fond of it as-is. It sounds like a mere semantic difference between this and [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) (or maybe no tag at all). It gets even less clear when I try to apply the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2370483):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Not really. It's related to formal specs... but not all languages have formal specs. And a lot of the questions don't seem about formal specs at all.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Formal spec discussions are on-topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Maybe? The usage is all over the place, hence why I have suspected this might just be another [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) tag.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Clearly not, or we'd not have an edit war over it.

---

The TL;DR here I'd like some formal discussion about the tag. What does it mean? When do we use it? Is it a synonym of [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax)? Do we just need to clean the excerpt up? Maybe rename it? Community input would be appreciated here, so we fix the problem going forward.

Comment: While this tag doesn't fit in with our regular definition of tags, it does serve a purpose that is distinct from syntax. Often there is ambiguity in the C and C++ spec about what behaviour is correct. This often causes different compilers to produce different behaviour for the same piece of valid code (or sometimes the question is whether it really is valid, and whether a given compiler is right to accept/reject it).

Comment: Somewhat related to the discussion of the validity of [tag:language-lawyer] questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418433/5899776

Comment: Previous general discussion on the tag: [Is 'language-lawyer' really an effective characterization, or a borderline meta-tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256510/2821954). Otherwise, [search result for specific meta questions about the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=language+lawyer+is%3Aq).

Comment: The referenced question seems to be asking about whether the values will sign extended or zero extended. The answer to that is somewhat ambiguous. In modern C and C++ signed integers are defined to be 2's complement, so it should be well defined that signed integer get sign extended, unsigned integer get zero extended, but previous standards would have left it as implementation detail. That would be a distinct question from the syntax of the language, as the syntax doesn't need to change for the end result to change due to targeting different hardware.

Comment: *"the tag itself is vague"* -- you quoted the excerpt. The tag's ["info"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info) says *"you are interested in the formal specification"*, which more clearly indicates a role for the formal language specification in answers. It's not a clear "answers must quote/reference the spec", but I think it's less vague than the excerpt. It might be worth bringing up the "info" when discussing the use of a tag.

Answer (score 20):

Language lawyering is absolutely not synonymous with syntax. The vast proportion of languages have very few "intricacies" in their syntax, rather it is the **semantics** of the language which are complex and have various edge cases or unexpected consequences.

Taking Java as an example: the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/index.html) has 19 chapters, of which only three are about the language's syntax ([2. Grammars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-2.html), [3. Lexical Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-3.html) and [19. Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-19.html) which is practically an appendix), and those chapters are some of the least complex.

Sampling the first five search results for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer):

- [Why can't the Java compiler infer Iterable from the contraints Iterable<? extends CharSequence> and () -> (Iterator)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58538083/12299000) - this question is about the rules for type inference, not syntax.
- [Why doesn't instanceof pattern matching work with else if in this particular case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72446186/12299000) - this question is about the scoping rules, not syntax.
- [foo(int, int) is picked over foo(int...)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72781849/12299000) - this question is about the method resolution rules, not syntax.
- [Is Iterable.forEach allowed to be parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72142627/12299000) - this question is about the contract of a standard library method, not syntax.
- [Why does it matter if I use a method reference or a lambda here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56304315/12299000) - this question is again about the rules for type inference, not syntax.

So if [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) were made a synonym of [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax), it would be an incorrect tag on all of these questions and many more. (That said, there are *some* questions in the search results which are about syntax, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52264638/12299000) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69469913/12299000).)

So you might ask, even if those five questions aren't about syntax, they're about quite different things, so should they really all have the same tag? My answer is **yes**, the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag is useful for these questions because a good answer to each of them probably requires expert knowledge of the language specification, and the expertise to interpret it correctly; and the primary purpose of tags is to enable experts to find questions they can answer. So here the tag is working as intended, and the tag [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) would not achieve the same goal for these questions.

Now, perhaps you might make the argument that the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag is redundant because these questions could instead be tagged with [jls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jls). My answer to that is:

- Not every language has a tag for questions about its specification, and users who ask questions may not know that there is a tag. Having a more popular tag like [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) makes it more likely that users will know to add the tag to their questions.
- If you're a nerd like me who reads the Java Language Specification for fun, it's probably not the only language specification you know some things about, and sometimes the ability to correctly interpret a formal specification is enough to answer a question even about a language you aren't an expert in.
- A secondary purpose of tags is to help people find Q&As in order to learn about a topic they are interested in. I follow the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag not just because it has questions I may be able to answer, but also because as a designer of programming languages I often find the posts interesting even when they are about languages I don't use. Actually it is probably the most interesting tag on the site for me.

Answer (score 14):

I think the tag is useful despite being somewhat meta. May need some cleanup to remove misplaced once after clarification is complete.

In my view the tag is for questions of "Explain WTF this line(s) of the code translated/error this way? And no, I don't need workarounds {links to coding answers}, I need pointers into language docs."

I generally do not expect this tag to be *edited in* by people looking at the question. It is definitely very easy to invalidate answers by adding the tag which is considered against the rules. As result I expect edit wars on that - whether OP needs a practical coding answer or somewhat theoretical explanation with links to language specification is OP's decision. It is ok to have two similar questions targeting practical and theoretical explanation separately and edit war on adding/removing the tag should be resolved that way - ask your own "language-lawyer" version. This is similar how we use language tags - it is essentially prohibited to add or remove language tags, but sometimes it is ok to re-tag *misplaced* language or remove incorrectly added once; it is encouraged (or even required) to ask the same question in multiple languages separately.

I think wiki excerpt is good (and I don't have suggestions to improve) - indeed some languages don't have a formal specification but that's why it includes "...authoritative specifications..." - if there is no documents about the language that people consider authoritative there is no point in using "language-lawyer" tag for that language as it will only result in opinion-based speculations.

My take on burnination criteria:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  It does not necessary describe content of the question, but definitely describes focus of the question and demands the particular type of an answer. It is quite unambiguous and in line with the other "answer" tags - language, DB, technology/library - it demands answers to be "authoritative" rather than "instructional".
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Absolutely - why a piece of code in a programming language can/can't be translated or behave in a particular way is the topic of SO. There are definitely questions that could be too theoretical for SO, but that is not different from many other tags.
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  Sort of. It somewhat says that OP either knows or don't need workarounds for the observed behavior. It also suggests that OP is able to read language's specification and would not need detailed explanation of terminology.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  Yes, it scopes down types of answers that are valid, again similar to language/library tags.

Other tags criteria:

- can one be an expert in the tag

  Absolutely. A true expert in understanding and interpreting language specification would very likely be aware of intricacies of multiple languages and be able to at very least read/validate questions and answer even if they are not an expert in a specific programing language. It is even expected that relatively large group - language designers - to be an expert in this.
- is it meta-tag

  To some extent. This tag almost never can be a single tag on a post and at least need a language tag to go along with it. It is somewhat similar in spirit to the "beginner"/"advanced" tag suggestion, but fortunately allows relatively clear criteria to evaluate answers - answer must use/cite the official language documentation - which can be confirmed by any member of the community.